# Is there meaning in the name Miyah?

Tags: names

I named my daughter Miyah. I wanted to take her name back to times when names meant something. I joined the poetic form of the Creator's Name (Yahweh/YHWH). I've been doing name research lately to dig at things. I see many definitions for the name pronounced *mee-ah* but nothing for how I pronounce my daughter's name: *mI-yah*.

Comment: JLUV, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking login/register above.

Comment: Why is this question picking up reopen votes? Anybody care to explain how this question is on-topic?

Comment: @Daniel, most other requests to understand the meaning of Jewish names are on topic, and I don't see enough of a difference between those and this one to warrant closure.

Comment: @Yishai Well I don't see why "I named my daughter abasdfda. Could you please tell me what significance that name has?" is a valid question. It's one thing if the OP has some reason to suspect that the name has some significance (like it's in Tanakh or it's a common Jewish name), but it's a completely different thing if the OP made up a name and then asks for its significance.

Comment: @Daniel. It probably came to attention recently because [I mentioned it in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22929393#22929393).

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the question correctly, you're seeking a meaning of the name *Miyah*, pronounced [`maj.a`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) (essentially like [the Indian tribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_peoples)'s name, so as to rhyme with the greeting *hiya*), in Hebrew.

I can't think of any in Hebrew, but [מיא](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%90) is pronounced roughly like that and means "water" in Aramaic.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, your intention was for your daughter's name to mean "from G-d"?

Traditional Jewish practice is in fact *not* to pronounce the four-letter name above. It's considered too holy for us to say. When it appears in Torah reading or prayer books, it is instead pronounced "Adonoi", meaning "master of me and all."

So I'm afraid you'll find little help here on how your daughter's name should be pronounced.

If you'd like to ask which traditional Hebrew names mean something similar (for instance, "Samuel" means "asked from God", or the girl's name Netanya means "God gave"), we'd be happy to try and help you.

Good luck!

Comment: Shalom, Netanya is a boy's name in every single occurrence of it in Tanach!

Comment: If I read the question correctly, it's asking for the meaning of Mi-yah, which I think you've correctly identified as "From God."

Comment: @Yahu: so? Yonah is indubitably a male name in Tanach too, but it's used nowadays for both genders.

Comment: There are many nice Jewish names for girls. Miriam starts with an "m" sound. Actually, "maya" or "mIya" as the questioner asked means "water". But she wants it to mean something else I guess.

Answer (score 3):

JLUV, there is no rule on how precise names need to be in their expressions.  Take the name cited by Shalom- "Shmuel".  The word is partially acronymized-the Sh comes from the word *she'iltihu*- *I requested him*; the *M* comes from the contracted prefix meaning *from*; *E-l* means *G-d*.  The vowel U following the M has no place in the meaning.

In your case, if you meant to express a relationship between your Daughter and G-d, Miyah is a fine name.

Answer (score 2):

I know the OP is no longer around the site (at least by the name JLUV), but I thought I'd add this.

The name Mee-yah could well be used to signify that the child is from G-d. The "Mee" at the beginning means "from", and the "yah" ending is one of G-d's names (or more like an abbreviation of G-d's name). The ending is prominent in many Jewish names (anyone should feel free to add to this short list):

Eliyah (a shortened form of Eliyahu, both of which are Anglicized to Elijah)
Tuvyah/Tovyah/Tuvia (among other spellings, rendered Tobias in Greek/English)
Yirmiyah/Yirmiyahu (Jeremiah)
Shmaryah
Oriyah
Yeshayah/Yeshayahu (Isaiah)

I know the OP was looking for meaning in the other pronunciation, but this is to encourage the more natural pronunciation because of its significant meaning, which seems to resonate so well with the OP.